# user can not be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I wrote one line of code in my jsp code

```
User u = (User)request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
```

and I get this error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - User cannot be resolved to a type
```

Why is this so? What should I look into?

Comment: Did you import the `User` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following line in your jsp:

```
<%@ page import="....User" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of *scriptlets* `<% %>` in JSP is deprecated now. Use EL as

```
<p>Welcome, ${user.name}</p>
```

Check out the [el](/questions/tagged/el) tag page for more info.